# Nopcommerce - make plugin to share my product description, image etc

Tags: plugins, nopcommerce

I want to make plugin in nop-commerce for sharing my product details on whats up.
So, how can i start?
Means, what should i need to make this plugin?

Answer (score 0):

This is too broad question, I suggest you to read [Developers guide](http://docs.nopcommerce.com/display/en/Developers+guide).

Moreover, you've to integrate WhatsApp api to your application using [WhastApp API nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Whatsapp.NET/) or any other available library.

[WhatsApp Share Plugin](http://www.nopcommerce.com/p/2471/whatsapp-share-plugin.aspx) already available on Market place!

Comment: i know about this plugin that will share link but i don't want to share link i want to share individuals(image , description, price...)

Comment: @user3178195: That's fine, this was just for your info.